# backbone relational validate related field

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js, tastypie, relational

I'm using backbone relational with django tastypie and I have problem with validation relations.

Let's say, I have a basic model with validate method:

```
MyModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
   urlRoot : '/api/v1/SampleModel/',
   relations : [
   {
      type: Backbone.HasOne,
      key: 'box',
      relatedModel: 'BoxModel',
      includeInJSON: 'id'
   }],

   validate : function(attr)
   {
      if(!attr.name)
      {
         console.log('attr name validation fail');
         return "C mon! name is srsly required!"; 
      }
      if(!attr.box)
      {
        console.log('attr box validation fail');
        console.log(attr.box);
        return "Damn! you forgot to set box!";
      }
   }
});
```

In some view i'm creating new MyModel instance with `box` as resource_uri of other object:

```
var BoxUri = '/api/v1/Box/3'
var NewModel = new MyModel();
NewModel.set('box',BoxUri);
NewModel.set('name','new name for model');
```

and here is meritum... when i make `save` on model, it always failure on `attr.box` validation and `attr.box` is `None`- even when all fields are set correctly.

What's interesting, if in `validate` function, do something like:

```
validate : function(attr){ 
   if(!attr.name)
       {
          console.log('attr name validation fail');
          return "C mon! name is srsly required!"; 
       }
   console.log(attr.box);

}
```

In above case, `attr.box` is displayed in console as desired object.

Of course, if I remove validation method, object is saved correctly, with appropriate relation etc..

As I red in documentation, on default, validation is run only when `save()` is called, so all fields are already set.. so how (and why) `validation` function know, that `attr.box` is empty?

Or maybe my approach is simply wrong?

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: When you check `if(!attr.box)` what's printed to the console by `console.log(attr.box);`

Comment: If i do `if(!attr.box)` console.log returns `null`. But if i console.log(attr.box) without checking condition, I'll get in console whole object.

Comment: Try to `console.log(attr.box);` before and after `if(!attr.box)` to see what happen.

Comment: I got 3x null:
1 null before condition,
1 null inside condition,
1 null after condition,

I think, even if it contain value, all console.log would show the same value - in console you will always see the most recent version of object.

Comment: So it has nothing to do with `if(!attr.box)` ? Maybe your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: I think it has something, because if I don't validate model, it works fine. If I don't check condition if(!attr.box) just only display it in console, it display correctly. Only if I add checking !attr.box - it fails. It seems like condition is checked before attr.box has been. I know that's weird, but it looks like that.

what's interesting, when I display attr.box, i get **whole** related object, not only resource_uri which I'm setting in view.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47778/discussion-between-asmith78-and-rida-benhammane)

Comment: I think, if in relations I define relation as specified Model, in validation process, backbone expect whole model - not only resource_uri. For tastypie, resource_uri is enough to set relation.
Question is, how to change behavior of backbone in validation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably i found solution.

modification in model definition:

```
MyModel = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
   idAttribute : 'id', //here i added declaration of id field
   urlRoot : '/api/v1/SampleModel/',
   relations : [
   {
      type: Backbone.HasOne,
      key: 'box',
      relatedModel: 'BoxModel',
      includeInJSON: 'resource_uri' // changed 'id' to 'resource_uri' probably it's not required at all
   }],

   validate : function(attr)
   {
      if(!attr.name)
      {
         console.log('attr name validation fail');
         return "C mon! name is srsly required!"; 
      }
      if(!attr.box)
      {
        console.log('attr box validation fail');
        console.log(attr.box);
        return "Damn! you forgot to set box!";
      }
   }
});
```

in view, i set in model just id instead resource_uri:

```
var BoxUri = '3'
var NewModel = new MyModel();
NewModel.set('box',BoxUri);
NewModel.set('name','new name for model');
```

after these two modifications, validation started working.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the values in the wrong object :

```
var BoxUri = '/api/v1/Box/3'
var NewModel = new MyModel();
NewModel.set('box',BoxUri); // NewModel instead of MyModel
NewModel.set('name','new name for model'); // NewModel instead of MyModel
```

---

Your problem is elsewhere, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Xw69U/) I setup an example that work well.

By the way, change the `relatedModel: 'BoxModel',` to `relatedModel: BoxModel,`

Comment: Well, you've right but unfortunately that was only typo in my example code. Issue still exists.